# Mockito не возвращает то что нужно!

Tags: java, тестирование, junit, mockito

```
public class ConnectionPointTest {

    @Test
    public void testMockito() throws IOException {

        DataInputStream dataInputStream = mock(DataInputStream.class);
        when(dataInputStream.readUTF()).thenReturn("Test");
        new JustTest(dataInputStream).doTest();


    }

    public class JustTest {
        DataInputStream dataInputStream;

        public JustTest(DataInputStream dataInputStream) {
            this.dataInputStream = dataInputStream;
        }

        public void doTest() throws IOException {
            String s = dataInputStream.readUTF();
            System.out.println(s);

        }

    }
}
```

Внедряю JUnit тестирование + Mockito в проект. При вызове `when(dataInputStream.readUTF()).thenReturn("Test");`

Выдает исключение:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:337)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
    at com.pav.avdonin.server.ConnectionPointTest.testMockito(ConnectionPointTest.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Вы сделали Mock для экземпляра `DataInputStream`, что по вашему должен вернуть метод `readUTF()`? Вам нужно сделать Mock под вызов этого метода, то есть "замокать" какие-то данные, которые он будет возвращать.

Comment: iksuy, я добавил тестовый код. Я наверное не так понимаю работу Mockito. Как я могу в этом коде "сделать Mock под вызов этого метода, то есть "замокать" какие-то данные"?

Comment: Судя по логу либо у вас что то не замокалось, либо это не весь код, т.к. NPE у пал в классе  DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:337)

Comment: @ Denis, код полный. Специально написал его для теста и показа как образца на stackoverflow. Но код же написано правильно? Я правильно понимаю как работает  метод when(). у Mockito?

Answer (score 2):

Мне помогли на англоязычном [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007620/mockito-does-not-return-what-i-need). Проблема была в том, что я пробовал "замокать" final метод:

```
public final String readUTF() throws IOException {
    return readUTF(this);
}
```

Mockito (v2.x) поддерживает это. На это требует дополнительной настройки.
Необходимо в папке `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/` создать файл с названием `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker,`открыть его через блокнот и добавить одну строку:

```
mock-maker-inline
```

Удачно все проходит при использовании зависимостей:
JUnit 4.12
Mockito 2.7.19